# update of kernel not used to remove all of 0 kB

Tags: kernel, updates, update-manager

When I use update software using the `software updater`, after the update there are always some updates left regarding the `update of kernels not used to remove`, that is the version `5.15.0` (signed kernel, header, etc.). They all size 0 kB. What does it mean?